# Time Window Issues On Snmp4j

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I need a solution for Time stamp problem in SNMP4J. How to solve this problem without restarting Java virtual Machine? We are stuck due to this problem.
If you have any idea, please suggest it.

Here is my sample code:

```
        {
        **TransportMapping<?> transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

        //target Creations:
        Target target = null;
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        target = new UserTarget();
        target.setAddress(new UdpAddress(inetAddress, port));
        target.setRetries(2);
        target.setTimeout(2500);
        target.setVersion(snmpVersion);
        target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
        target.setSecurityName(new OctetString("name1"));


        //Usm Obj Creations:
        byte[] engineId1=MPv3.createLocalEngineID();
        USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),new OctetString(engineId1), 0);
        snmp.listen();


        byte[] engineId=snmp.discoverAuthoritativeEngineID(target.getAddress(), 2500);
        usm=new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),new OctetString(engineId), 0);
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);
        snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString("name1"), new OctetString(engineId),new UsmUser(new OctetString("name1"), AuthMD5.ID,new OctetString("*123"), PrivDES.ID, new OctetString("Y:123"))));
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
            pdu = new ScopedPDU();
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oidValue)));
        pdu.setType(PDU.GETNEXT);
        pdu.setRequestID(new Integer32(1));
        out.println("Sending Request to Agent...");
        ResponseEvent response1 = snmp.getNext(pdu, target);
        // Process Agent Response
        if (response1 != null) {
            out.println("Got Response from Agent");
            PDU responsePDU = response1.getResponse();
            if (responsePDU != null) {
                int errorStatus = responsePDU.getErrorStatus();
                int errorIndex = responsePDU.getErrorIndex();
                String errorStatusText = responsePDU.getErrorStatusText();
                if (errorStatus == PDU.noError) {
                    out.println("Snmp Get Response = " + responsePDU.getVariableBindings());
                } else {
                    out.println("Error: Request Failed");
                    out.println("Error Status = " + `enter code here`errorStatus);
                    out.println("Error Index = " + errorIndex);
                    out.println("Error Status Text = " + errorStatusText);
                }
            } else {
                out.println("Error: Response PDU is null");
            }
        } else {
            out.println("Error: Agent Timeout... ");
        }
        snmp.close();**
    }
```

With the above code, I can discover a new `engine_id` but i can't use it. If i use that `engineId` it throws `usmUnknownEngineId` error.

Comment: Please show us some example code.

Comment: thanks Ronnie,please suggest any idea you have